# Cannot build C# project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am an experienced developer who is completely new to C# and windows development.

I would like to contribute to [Rocksmith custom song creator](https://code.google.com/p/rocksmith-custom-song-creator/) with a simple feature, but I don't even know how to build and run the project in Visual Studio 2012. I cloned the git repository, double clicked on `devtools/devtools.csproj` then `Debug -> Start Debugging` but I get an error about not being able to start a class directly.

You can browse the source code of the project at: https://code.google.com/p/rocksmith-custom-song-creator/source/browse/

Comment: Conceptually it is incorrect to "able to start a class directly."

Comment: Right-Click the project in the Solution Explorer, choose *Properties...*, set the application type to *Windows-application* and the start object to `Program`. Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, you have selected a sub-project in your solution to be the starting-project.
See, if there is project that defines a Window (WinForms or WPF), right-click this project and select it as starting project.

---

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can specify which project or projects within a multi-project solution Visual Studio will build and debug first.

To set a single startup project

1. In Solution Explorer, select the desired startup project within your solution.
2. On the Project menu, choose Set as StartUp Project.

Comment: It seems that the solution has multiple projects. I don't know how to build and launch the app :S Sorry if my question is naive, I am a Unix guy used to emacs/vi this IDE is really confusing to me.

Comment: If you had these steps until Start->Debug, you've come far. See, if a Project in your solution is in black bold letters. This is the marking for the starting project. See, if you have any files like `MainWindow.xaml` of `Form1.form`, these should be startable.

Answer (score 1):

The .csproj is just a project, you need to put that into a Solution (or open the solution included, if any)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `.sln` file? Probably that's the one you must open.